# Android Driver for Lepton Thermal Camera

Tags: android, infrared, uvc, flir

I am trying to connect flir lepton camera to an android device using usb, does this require the driver? The official website only has the software on linux, windows and macOS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok, i just edited the problem.